# iptables destination ip and port

Tags: linux, iptables, redirect, linux-networking

I am looking for a way to forward all traffic(to any port) from a pc to a certain ip.

Looking at the rule below :

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 --jump DNAT --to-destination 129.94.5.88:5000
```

this tells me all traffic destined for port 443 should be diverted to `129.94.5.88:5000`. How do I change this rule to say :

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport "ANY DESTINATION PORT" --jump DNAT --to-destination 129.94.5.88:5000
```

---

Also I would like to know how to do redirection based on destination ip not port. So looking this rule again :

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8443 --jump DNAT --to-destination 129.94.5.88:5000
```

How do I change this to redirect based on destintion IP (lets say `8.8.8.8`) rather than port ?

Comment: 1) Remove the `--dport 443` requirement.  2) Replace `--dport 8443` with `-d 8.8.8.8`.  3) Read the man page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first, do not specify `--dport` parameter, this will mean "any port":

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --jump DNAT --to-destination 129.94.5.88:5000
```

---

For the second, change `--dport` parameter with `-d` parameter for destination host:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 8.8.8.8 --jump DNAT --to-destination 129.94.5.88:5000
```

Comment: I don't think that `--dport xx` means "any port".  If I add a rule to drop traffic using `-p udp --dport 6081` I see `193  242K DROP       udp  --  gw1_br gw2_br  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:6081`